# C++ | How Do I Loop an If Statement Without Returning a Value Each Time

Tags: c++, function, loops, boolean, return-value

I have a loop within a function that increments through an array checking each element to see if it matches the parameter of the function.

My problem is the requirements for returning a value. Since returning a value completes the function, if one wrong match returns false and I'm required to return a value at every control path, then I wont be able to check any of the other elements within the array to see if they match.

Most of my experience is in AS3, in which this function structure does work. How would I go about structuring this function properly in C++?

Function: It's purpose is to check if an inputted command exists and return a boolean if true or false

```
bool Commands(string _input)
{
    string cmds[] = { "login", "logout", "exit" };

    int i = 0;
    do {
        if (_input == cmds[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i == sizeof(cmds))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < sizeof(cmds));
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(cmds)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `return std::find(std::begin(cmds), std::end(cmds), _input) != std::end(cmds);` ?

Comment: There's not a lot of point having a function like this return a boolean value - your program's almost certain to need similar code to work out *which* of the commands has been entered, so you might as well return an `int` - the value `i`, and say `-1` for an invalid command; then you can use the `int` value in a `switch` statement.  With a little more effort, you could create an `enum` with values for each command and an invalid sentinel.  That said, directly using `if (input == "login") ... else if (input == "logout") ... else // invalid ...;` in the caller is often best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are looping, return `true` when you find the value you are looking for. Otherwise, when the loop completes, you can simply return `false` after the loop.

```
bool Commands(string _input) {
    string cmds[] = { "login", "logout", "exit" };

    int i = 0;
    do {
        if (_input == cmds[i]) {
            return true; // we found it!
        }
        i++;
    } while (i < sizeof(cmds));
    return false; // we didn't find it.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a few improvements:

`sizeof(cmds)` returns the size *in bytes* of `cmds`, which will be `sizeof(string) * 3` or for example 96 on a 64-bit system; your loop will run off the end of the array, causing undefined behaviour. One option is to use `sizeof(cmds)/sizeof(*cmds)` to get the number of elements, but for your purposes it would be simpler to use a `std::vector` with an initializer list:

```
std::vector<string> cmds { "login", "logout", "exit" };
```

Next, you can replace your `do` loop with a `for` loop, and `sizeof` with the `.size()` member function of `std::vector`. If the input doesn’t match, you simply don’t `return` and proceed to the next iteration of the loop. If the function hasn’t returned after the loop, then no item was found, so you can `return false`.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < cmds.size(); ++i)
  if (_input == cmds[i])
    return true;
return false;
```

You can also replace the loop with a call to the `std::find` algorithm from the standard `<algorithm>` header:

```
return std::find(std::begin(cmds), std::end(cmds), _input) != std::end(cmds);
```

Comment: Prefer `std::array` here

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I made the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For starters it is better to declare the parameter as constant reference.
There is no need to declare an array of objects of the type `std::string`. It is much better to declare an array of string literals.

The loop is wrong. For example this expression `sizeof(cmds)` does not make sence in conditions like for example this

```
 if (i == sizeof(cmds))
```

The number of elements in the array is calculated like

```
sizeof(cmds) / sizeof( *cmds)
```

The function can be much simplified using standard algorithms.

Just write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

bool Commands( const std::string &s )
{
    const char * cmds[] = { "login", "logout", "exit" };

    return std::find( std::begin( cmds ), std::end( cmds ), s ) != std::end( cmds );
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Commands( "logout" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Commands( "hello" ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
true
false
```

If you want to use a loop in the function then it can look like it is shown below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

bool Commands( const std::string &s )
{
    const char * cmds[] = { "login", "logout", "exit" };
    const size_t N = sizeof( cmds ) / sizeof( *cmds );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < N && s != cmds[i] ) i++;

    return i != N;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Commands( "logout" ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Commands( "hello" ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It is not a good style of programming when a simple function has several exits and moreover in most cases it is not necessary.